# window.opener.location.assign is not working

Tags: javascript

I want to add the additional parameter to the parent window. However, it not working using the following code. I am using this in my ASP.NET project

```
 var URL = window.opener.location.href + '&type=Customer';
        window.opener.location.assign(URL);
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
```

When I assign the explicit URL like this `window.opener.location.assign('www.example.com?status=Active&type=Customer');`. Then it is working properly.

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) docs state: "If the opener is not on the same origin as the current page, functionality of the opener object is limited. For example, variables and functions on the window object are not accessible.". Might be what's happening in your case.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter only difference is the concatenation of the URL. does it affect the properties on window.opener?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter, it is the same domain. I just want to add one additional parameter to the existing URL